# Babylonian algorithm function using while loop

Tags: python

I am struggling on a Babylonian algorithm to find a square root of 'a':

1. Take a guess: pick some number x.
2. Check how good is our guess, by computing abs(x2 - a). If it’s close enough (for example, less than 10^-6), we’re done.
3. Otherwise, calculate an improved guess (x + a/x) / 2; this replaces the previous value of x and we repeat from the test.

I have no idea where the while loop should come to, and what to do if the improved guess is still not correct.

I have tried to every code under the 'while True' loop, but that made it even more confusing. This is the draft code below:

```
def babylonian(a,x):
    difference = abs(x ** 2 - a)
    improved_guess = 0.5 * (a / x + x)
    if difference < 10 ** -6:
        print("Guess is right")
    while difference > 10 ** -6:
        if (improved_guess ** 2 - a) < 10 ** -6:
            break
```

If I enter (4, 1) for instance, the terminal does not give any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you algorithm first find the difference using initial guess if it is ok then while loop wont execute if not the find the appropriate guess inside while loop an you have to return the final guess from the function:

```
def babylonian(a,x):
    difference = abs(x ** 2 - a)
    if difference < 10 ** -6:
        print("Guess is right")
    while difference > 10 ** -6:
        x = 0.5 * (a / x + x)
        difference = abs(x ** 2 - a)
    return x
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I also want to ask if it is fine assigning the same x variable inside the while loop when there is already a x existing as a parameter.

Comment: It is fine if initial value of parameter x is not needed to be same inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Follow your recipe:

TOLERANCE = 1e-6

def babylonian(target, guess):  # Take a guess

```
# Check how good is our guess, by computing abs(x2 - a).
# If it’s close enough (for example, less than 10^-6), we’re done.
while abs(guess*guess - target) > TOLERANCE: 
    print(guess)


    # Otherwise, calculate an improved guess (x + a/x) / 2; 
    new_guess = (guess + target/guess) / 2

    # this replaces the previous value of x
    guess = new_guess

    # and we repeat from the test.


return guess
```

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes to your code:

```py
def Babylonian(a, x):     
    difference = abs(x ** 2 - a)
    if difference < 0.000001:
        print("Correct", x)
    else:
        while difference > 0.000001:
            x = 0.5 * (x + a/x)
            difference = abs(x ** 2 - a)
        print("Correct ", x)
```

You need to update the value of x in the while loop, otherwise it will go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the helpful answer. Tip: use four leading spaces on each line for code formatting. There are a bunch of other options too, click the formatting options help link for info.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Hope it is better now. Do suggest any changes if needed.

Comment: Much easier to read now, thanks. I didn't review the code in detail, but I think I see one error: `d` and `difference` were supposed to be the same variable, right?